# Color codes for tput setf

Tags: bash, shell, terminfo, tput

I am sourcing a file with this content

```
export fgBlack8="$(tput setf 0)";
export fgRed8="$(tput setf 1)";
export fgGreen8="$(tput setf 2)";
export fgYellow8="$(tput setf 3)";
export fgBlue8="$(tput setf 4)";
export fgMagenta8="$(tput setf 5)";
export fgCyan8="$(tput setf 6)";
export fgWhite8="$(tput setf 7)";

export bgBlack8="$(tput setb 0)";
export bgRed8="$(tput setb 1)";
export bgGreen8="$(tput setb 2)";
export bgYellow8="$(tput setb 3)";
export bgBlue8="$(tput setb 4)";
export bgMagenta8="$(tput setb 5)";
export bgCyan8="$(tput setb 6)";
export bgWhite8="$(tput setb 7)";
```

according to this link: https://linux.101hacks.com/ps1-examples/prompt-color-using-tput/

Then, when testing the Colors with a few commands like this

```
echo -e "${fgBlack8}fgBlack8"
echo -e "${fgRed8}fgRed8"
echo -e "${fgGreen8}fgGreen8"
echo -e "${fgYellow8}fgYellow8"
echo -e "${fgBlue8}fgBlue8"
echo -e "${fgMagenta8}fgMagenta8"
echo -e "${fgCyan8}fgCyan8"
echo -e "${fgWhite8}fgWhite8"
```

I receive the following output:

[image: Colors scrambled]

Displaying red as blue, yellow as cyan and vice versa. Are the codes on the website wrong or am I using it wrong and produce correct Color mappings by accident?

Comment: You appear to be confusing the `setaf/setab` colors and the `setf/setb` colors. See [man 5 terminfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html) for details

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That helped, thank you. I checked man bash because I did not know which page to look at and (surprise surprise) did not find anything and hence used the sloppily composed article.

Comment: Happens to us all. I just recall from somewhere in the past that `terminfo` was the place to go. Good luck with your scripting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `tput` command, then it's logical to start with

```
$ man tput
```

which from SEE ALSO will take you to

```
$ man terminfo
```

and you'll discover that

> The setaf/setab and setf/setb capabilities take a single numeric  argu-
>          ment  each.
>   The terminal hardware is
>          free to map these as it likes, but the RGB values indicate normal loca-
>          tions in color space.
>
> ```
>                 Color       #define       Value       RGB
>                 black     COLOR_BLACK       0     0, 0, 0
>                 red       COLOR_RED         1     max,0,0
>                 green     COLOR_GREEN       2     0,max,0
>                 yellow    COLOR_YELLOW      3     max,max,0
>                 blue      COLOR_BLUE        4     0,0,max
>                 magenta   COLOR_MAGENTA     5     max,0,max
>                 cyan      COLOR_CYAN        6     0,max,max
>                 white     COLOR_WHITE       7     max,max,max
> ```
>
> The argument values of setf/setb historically correspond to a different
>      mapping, i.e.,
>
> ```
>                 Color       #define       Value       RGB
>                 black     COLOR_BLACK       0     0, 0, 0
>                 blue      COLOR_BLUE        1     0,0,max
>                 green     COLOR_GREEN       2     0,max,0
>                 cyan      COLOR_CYAN        3     0,max,max
>                 red       COLOR_RED         4     max,0,0
>                 magenta   COLOR_MAGENTA     5     max,0,max
>                 yellow    COLOR_YELLOW      6     max,max,0
>                 white     COLOR_WHITE       7     max,max,max
> ```

Comment: You can also take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dtmilano/4055d6df5b6e4ea87c5a72dc2d604193) to see the colors in action